# How to get permission for google photo or deny

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I use RecyclerView with pictures from Gallery.

in my adapter:

```
public void onBindViewHolder:
------
  bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(activity.getContentResolver(), uriImg);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap );
----
```

in app I choose pictire for item and save URI:

```
  Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
```

When choosen pictures with  Galery, RecyclerView show this picture in item. But when picture choosen with Photos (google photo) I get SecurityException.

How get permission for google photo or how to deny choose with google photo?

[image]

URI from Galery:content://media/external/images/media/34
URI from GOOGLE PHOTO: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F34/ACTUAL/1186708631

my exception:

```
01-03 09:53:57.612 4762-4762/info.upump.wardrobe3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: info.upump.wardrobe3, PID: 4762
                                                                    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider.MediaContentProvider from ProcessRecord{db51992 4762:info.upump.wardrobe3/u0a78} (pid=4762, uid=10078) that is not exported from uid 10045
                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3550)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4778)
                                                                        at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2018)
                                                                        at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1468)
                                                                        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1088)
                                                                        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:942)
                                                                        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:662)
                                                                        at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.getBitmap(MediaStore.java:866)
                                                                        at info.upump.wardrobe3.adapter.SubItemAdapter.createMask(SubItemAdapter.java:133) // this link to "bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(activity.getContentResolver(), uriImg);"
                                                                        at info.upump.wardrobe3.adapter.SubItemAdapter.onBindViewHolder(SubItemAdapter.java:66)
                                                                        at info.upump.wardrobe3.adapter.SubItemAdapter.onBindViewHolder(SubItemAdapter.java:42)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6400)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6433)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5377)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5640)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5482)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5478)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2215)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1542)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1502)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3625)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3067)
                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:934)
                                                                        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:973)
                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:713)
                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1389)
                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:783)
                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1080)
                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.mea
```

---

Image I get with:

```
 Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");

                getActivity().startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SubFragment.CHOOSE_PHOTO_RESULT);
```

next:

```
    onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      uri = data.getData();
//    next I write this URI in DB
    }
```

and in adapter I get uriImg from DB

Comment: What is the security exception?

Comment: @JoxTraex   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider.impl.MediaContentProvider from ProcessRecord

Comment: Post the full error in your original post

Comment: @JoxTraex  adde  error and uri

Comment: How do you get uriImg are you getting it from the intent.getData() ?

Comment: Also refer to this: https://www.android-examples.com/pick-image-from-gallery-in-android-programmatically/ . One thing is to ensure that you are starting the activity and consuming the result and resolving the data through the contentresolver instead of going directly through MediaStore.

Comment: @JoxTraex  added in post

Comment: If you lookat the link that I posted, it may be that the way you're getting the image may not be correct